# How to stop refreshing HTML table rendering until it is completely drawn

Tags: html, css

I am reading a (fairly big) amount of data from a DB, and printing it in HTML in a JS DataTable (https://datatables.net/)
The DB and HTML creation is fairly fast (for the amount of data read, I mean), around 100ms of server execution time, but I can literally see the table being created and "adjusted" to be responsive, taking around 3 seconds on my (fairly fast) machine.

So, I was wondering... Other than maybe putting all the HTML in a PHP variable and printing it all at once (didn't try it yet), is there a way to tell the browser something like "do not render this element (table) until you find the </table>?", because it seems it's losing a lot of time trying to optimize the table width every time new rows are added, without waiting for the last one.

Maybe setting the table style to hidden, and then make it visible only when the document is ready?
But I was looking for some specific HTML/CSS tags/options to stop redrawing it until it was fully received.

Comment: What happens if you output the table element with style display: none then change that with a bit of JS following the output of the end table tag?

Comment: I didn't try it yet, first I was looking if there was a specific CSS/HTML tag/style